Making internal css code with an ID external css so that the ID is still valid
I have CSS in an internal style tag in the header but with an id as in  <style id="mks">...css ...</style>.  Now I want to make this css external, let us say in "myfile.css".  The obvious thing to do is now to place a line like
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myfile.css">

in my HTML code, but what do I have to do for having the id="mks" still being valid?

Just give link the id="mks". But for what do you need it?

and for the sake of records a css file is not expected to contain html elements but just css rules.. so the id wouldn't have any place there. it's quite an odd question because id is an attribute relative to html elements and it's not clear the full picture of your concern that maybe is hiding further misconceptions
